# include(): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, php-include

This might just come as a very silly question, but i am really frustrated of this not working. 
I have a home file `(home.php)` which has contains `<? include ("/production/fetch_order.php"); ?>`. As it can be seen i am trying to access a file from home.php. The file is named as `fetch_order.php` which is in the production folder. My path is correct, the spellings are absolutely correct too. However i end up with this error:

```
Warning: include(/production/fetch_order.php) [function.include]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/home.php on line 119

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/production/fetch_order.php'
for inclusion (include_path='.:/path/to/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in
/path/to/home.php on line 119
```

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using an absolute path (`/`) at the start of the line, you need to remove that slash and it would be a relative path, example:

```
production/fetch_order.php
```

When adding a slash, it starts at the root directory of your system, without it, it looks in the current directory.

Comment: Does the file *actually* exists or you need to enter the correct path to the file. Is there a folder named `production` in the same directory where `home.php` is?

Comment: The file does exist. The home.php and the production folder are at the same level, and the production folder has a file named fetch_order.php

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Yes PHP7 spits a warning about the trailing slash while other versions of PHP don't. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the path you're referencing ('/production/fetch_order.php') is provided *either* as an absolute path from the file system root directory or as a relative path from the current file (`home.php`).

```
include('production/fetch_order.php');
```

OR

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/production/fetch_order.php');
```

Comment: Start by using `echo dirname(__FILE__);` to find out what directory `home.php` is being executed in. Confirm that `production/fetch_order.php` exists _within_ that directory.

Comment: Ok. And there's a directory in that path named `production` that contains a file called `fetch_order.php`?

Comment: Also, what error are you seeing? If none is showing, is there a chance that the file is being included but your script isn't doing anything?

Comment: The file does exist. and the errors are the warning that are being shown as mentioned in the code above.

Comment: try `echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/production/fetch_order.php';` and copy the result into a terminal to see if it gets you to the file?

Comment: However, if i paste that command into `Go to Folder`. It takes me to that file in the finder!

Comment: Is PHP executing as you or as the user for a webserver? If the server, does _it_ have permission?

Comment: I am running it on the localhost. I am able to access other php files that are at same folder level but i am unable to include any file which is in another folder from there.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

Seems that path is not correct, try:

```
<? include ("production/fetch_order.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Try var_dump(dirname(__FILE__)); or var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))); to debug

Comment: Kind of looks like it, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand that one?

Comment: If caller php file gives you "/right/path/to/file/production/fetch_order.php" then seems it is fetch_order.php ! It call itself ?

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507